# How to distort 2d perlin noise?

Tags: unity, perlin-noise

I am using Unity's 2D `Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, y)` function and I would like to make it distorted. What I mean is described with this picture I made:

[image]

How can I do that? What transformations should I apply to `Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, y)` to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want an effect called [Domain Warping](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/warp/warp.htm).

This is when you layer your noise using [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition):

- First you sample some noise based on your input position
- Then you add the results to your input position to get a shifted position
- Then you sample some noise *at that shifted position* to produce your final output

It's called domain warping because you're distorting the space of inputs to your noise function (the function's domain)

[image: Example of domain warped noise]

On the left is basic Perlin noise, and on the right the same noise with a small amount of domain warping applied (with topographic contours to help show the effect)

In Unity C# code it might look a bit like this:

```
public float DistortedNoise(float x, float y, float distortionStrength) {
    // Take two samples from our distortion function
    // (Shifted in space by > 1 so they don't correlate with each other)
    float xDistortion = distortionStrength * Distort(x + 2.3f, y + 2.9f);
    float yDistortion = distortionStrength * Distort(x - 3.1f, y - 4.3f);

    return Mathf.PerlinNoise(x + xDistortion, y + yDistortion);
}

float Distort(float x, float y) {
    // Optionally, you can scale your internal noise frequency
    // or layer several octaves of noise to control the wiggly shapes.
    float wiggleDensity = 4.7f; 
    return Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * wiggleDensity, y * wiggleDensity);
}
```